# How can I make a layout like this in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, responsive, flutter-web

I have trying to implement layout like this using Flutter.
[image]

I tried using Wrap Widget, but Wrap widget is giving me output like this
[image]

I don't want a vertical gap between boxes.

Comment: Try to build a row of columns.

Comment: that solution wont work. because i will get random size boxes with different height. If i use row with three items per row.. it will render the same layout as Wrap Widget.

Comment: You might want to check out [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) or [waterfall_flow](https://pub.dev/packages/waterfall_flow).

Comment: CustomMultiChildLayout is complex to implement . But Flutter_staggered_grid_view solved my problem. Thanks to all <3.

Comment: That is why you have a row of columns and not a column of rows of items. Row keeps the 3 columns near eachother. Inside the Columns items can have different sizes since they do not depend on eachother.

Comment: @stacktrace2234 The widget order is left to right and then top to bottom. The code to sort the widgets into the columns can become quite ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make above layout using flutter_staggered_grid_view

Here is the sample code for above solution.

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  mainAxisSpacing: 3,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("box 1")),
      ),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("Box 2")),
      ),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("box 3")),
      ),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("Box 4")),
      ),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 50,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("Box 5")),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

you need to import

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
```

Answer (score -1):

try using try using Row column with Expanded(flex: 2 , child: box)